# ember-data: consult backend for an unsaved model

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I'd like to consult the backend for an unsaved model (response) to be used in a controller.  When I do this:

```
//in my route
model: function(params) {
  var response = this.store.find('response', {folder: params.folder_id});
}
```

and my backend responds with:

response: [
    {text:testing, selections:[1,2,3,4], comments: [1,2,3,4,5]}
  ]

I get "Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push`", fair enough.

If I return a single object instead:

```
response: {text:testing, selections:[1,2,3,4], comments: [1,2,3,4,5]}
```

The model doesn't have any properties set on it.

```
model.get('text'); //undefined
```

Is it reasonable to ask the backend to create and pass back an unsaved model?  I can build the model in the front-end but this is sort of a pain because all of my relationships are async (and they are 2-3 wide and deep in this case) so I need a few round trips.  I'd just rather have the backend be the authority on this.

I suppose an alternative would be to save a sparse record and let the backend fill it in and return it.  The disadvantage being that when people visit this route, data is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it reasonable to ask the backend to create and pass back an unsaved
>   model?

I think this violates the REST GET as it's not saved/part of a collection.

So I'll either save the object and pull it back up.  Or batch a set of requests from the frontend for all of the saved components that will make up the new response object.